# Subset rows excluse special values

Tags: r

I want to subset rows which do not contain special values. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,2,3,4,4),b=c(-9999,2,3,4,5,6),c=c(2,3,4,-9999,2,4))

  a     b     c
1 1 -9999     2
2 2     2     3
3 2     3     4
4 3     4 -9999
5 4     5     2
6 4     6     4
```

df has many rows and columns , I want to subset the rows which don't contain -9999. Expect result as follow codes:

```
df[which(df$a!=-9999,df$b!=-9999,df$c!=-9999),]

  a b c
2 2 2 3
3 2 3 4
5 4 5 2
6 4 6 4
```

when columns are to many to type above logical judge, how to subset it?

Comment: `df[rowSums(df == -9999) == 0, ]`

Comment: Read your data with `na.strings=c("-9999")`, then use `complete.cases`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
temp <- which(df == "-9999",arr.ind = T)

df[-unique(temp[,1]),]
  a b c
2 2 2 3
3 2 3 4
5 4 5 2
6 4 6 4
```